# Let $G$ be a group and $A$ be a normal abelian subgroup, where $\overline{G}=G/A$. Show that $\overline{g}a = gag^{-1}$ is a left action.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-actions, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $A$ be a normal abelian subgroup, where $\overline{G}=G/A$. Show that $\overline{g}a=gag^{-1}$ is a left action of $\overline{G}$ on $A$.

Let $\overline{g_1},\overline{g_2}\in\overline{G}$ be arbitrary. The following computations show that $\overline{g}a=gag^{-1}$ is a left action:

\begin{align}
\overline{1}a&=1a1^{-1} \\
&=a
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\overline{g_1}(\overline{g_2}a)&=\overline{g_1}(g_2ag_2^{-1}) \tag{$\clubsuit$}\\
&=g_1g_2ag_2^{-1}g_1^{-1} \\
&=(g_1g_2)a(g_1g_2)^{-1} \\
&=\overline{g_1g_2}a
\end{align}

I encounter difficulty in showing the action is well-defined; that is, the action of a coset on an element of $A$ is uniquely determined regardless of what representative we choose.

To prove the action is well-defined, we let $g_1,g_1^*\in\overline{g_1}$ and $g_2,g_2^*\in\overline{g_2}$ and show $\overline{g_1g_2}a=\overline{g_1^*g_2^*}a$. We have that $g_1^*=g_1a_1$ and $g_2^*=g_2a_2$ for some $a_1,a_2\in A$.

The following computation is where I encounter difficulty:

\begin{align}
\overline{g_1^*}(\overline{g_2^*}a)&=\overline{g_1a_1}(\overline{g_2a_2}a) \\
&=g_1a_1(g_2a_2aa_2^{-1}g_2^{-1})a_1^{-1}g_1^{-1} \\
&=g_1a_1(g_2(a_2a_2^{-1})ag_2^{-1})a_1^{-1}g_1^{-1} \tag{$\ast$}\\
&=g_1a_1(g_2ag_2^{-1})a_1^{-1}g_1^{-1} \tag{$\star$}\\
&=\overline{g_1^*}(\overline{g_2}a) \\
&\neq\overline{g_1g_2}a
\end{align}

We used the fact $A$ is abelian to make the simplification in $(\ast)$, but we cannot do the same to simplify $(\star)$ because every element of $G$ does not necessarily commute with every element of $A$.

Another thought is that $g_2ag_2^{-1}\in A$ since $A$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. We could continue our computation as follows:

\begin{align}
g_1a_1(g_2ag_2^{-1})a_1^{-1}g_1^{-1}&=g_1(a_1a_1^{-1})(g_2ag_2^{-1})g_1^{-1}\\
&=g_1g_2ag_2^{-1}g_1^{-1} \\
&=(g_1g_2)a(g_1g_2)^{-1} \\
&=\overline{g_1g_2}a
\end{align}

We conclude $\overline{g_1^*g_2^*}a=\overline{g_1^*}(\overline{g_2^*}a)=\overline{g_1g_2}a$ since we already proved the action for arbitrary cosets in $(\clubsuit)$.

Comment: Indeed, you just need to use that $A$ is normal to complete the proof.

Comment: It's not clear how that helps, @Wuestenfux.

Comment: Note first that $G$ acts on the normal subgroup $A$ by conjugation. As you know, this is equivalent to a group homomorphism $\varphi : G \to S(A)$, where $S(A)$. Show that $A \le \ker(\varphi)$.

Comment: You haven't defined $S(A)$, @AndreasCaranti.

Comment: Thanks @Shaun, I intended to do that, but I forgot. It's the group of permutations of the set $A$. (And of course we could replace $S(A)$ here with the group a=of automorphisms of $A$.)